# make error in conda env need libpython3.9.a but only have libpython3.9.so

Tags: centos7, uwsgi, python-3.9, anaconda3

I'm using centos7 and latest anaconda release with python3.9 to build a web server, but `pip install uwsgi` returned an error: "libpython3.9.a" not found. Only "libpython3.9.so" was provided by anaconda3.

Seems that there are some solutions for macos and debian, but nothing found for centos7, should I yum install something?

Comment: Not sure without seeing the linker command options, but maybe a [temporary workaround for macOS](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/2270#issuecomment-758211435) would work? (symbolic link to `libpython3.9.so` for `libpython3.9.a`)

Comment: linking the library makes it possible to install uwsgi, but the installation is not valid, every web request will kill the uwsgi worker with SIGSEGV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use make to install python source code for a temp dir
2. find lib/libpython3.9.a in your python install dir
3. copy the lib/libpython3.9.a to your conda env path (eg: anaconda3/envs//lib/python3.9/config-3.9-x86_64-linux-gnu/),this path from install uwsgi error log(like, gcc: error: xxx/libpython3.9.a: No such file or directory)
4. rerun pip install uwsgi and fix it

Comment: yes, that's a solution

Comment: Where do you get the source code?

Comment: I don't think this is the solution. I copied the `libpython3.9.a` after building Python 3.9 from source. But the copied library seemed to have been linked against many Python 3.9 source directory contained packages. Hence, attempting to build uWSGI with the copied `libpython3.9.a` reported many libraries as not found and failed!

Comment: @tash a file is static libaray file, not connect else lib. plz give me more error details or log, i will trying to help you